# Check the convergence of the series : Which test do we apply?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Check the convergence of the following series:

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^4+n}}$
- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+1)^{n^2}}}$

For the first series do we use the comparison test? But with which sequence do we compare $\frac{n^2+1}{n^4+n}$ ? Do we maybe do the following? $$\frac{n^2+1}{n^4+n}<\frac{n^2+n^2}{n^4+n}<\frac{n^2+n^2}{n^4}=\frac{2n^2}{n^4}=\frac{2}{n^2}$$

As for the second series I thought that we could use the ratio test but I am not sure if that works because we get $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}}{\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+1)^{n^2}}}=\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)^2}(n+1)^{n^2}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}n^{n^2}}=\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)^2+n^2}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}n^{n^2}}$$ So is it better to apply an other test here?

Answer (score 2):

For the second, it is better to use the root test.

$$\lim_{\infty}a_n^\frac 1n=\lim_{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$$

think of
$$\lim_{\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})^n=e$$

Comment: Ahh yes!! Is my approach for the first series right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. You used the comparison test. $0\le a_n\le \frac{2}{n^2}$ with $\sum \frac{2}{n^2}$ convergent. So, your series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that the terms of the second sum decay exponentially: Using $\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$ for $x\to0$, $$\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+1)^{n^2}}=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n^2}=\exp\left(n^2\ln\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\right)=O(1)\exp\left(-n\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

The first one is fine, for the second one, by $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n}\ge 2$, we have

$$\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+1)^{n^2}}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}\le\frac1{2^n}$$